# Android NDK can't find stlport

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm trying to compile a native library (derived from WebRTC) by using android NDK rev8b. I get the following error:

```
android_ndk/android-ndk-r8b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6.x-google/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lstlport_static
```

So it can't find the stl library.

I have installed `libmagic-dev`.

The version of the distribution (as returned by `/proc/version`) is:

```
Linux version 2.6.32-40-generic (buildd@yellow) (gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) ) #87-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 6 00:56:56 UTC 2012
```

**EDIT**
I have the same problem with the revision 8d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I had forgotten to specify:

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L/ndk-path/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/libs/armeabi

in the Android.mk file

Answer (score 1):

See http://docs.huihoo.com/android/ndk/r5/CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.html

You must set in your Application.mk, for example:

```
APP_STL := stlport_static
```

or `stlport_shared`

Comment: I had set it. The problem was in the Android.mk: I had to specify the LOCAL_LDLIBS

Comment: no, NDK would add `-L<stlport>` automatically, if Application.mk is there.

Comment: I understand that you it did not work without adding stlport to LOCAL_LDLIBS. But this means that there is some problem with your build environment (Application.mk or Android.mk or NDK setup). I hope that the workaround you found will continue to work.