# Android NDK r10: std::string has not been declared

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, std

I'm having problems with the android ndk r10. I get the following: std::string has not been declared. I watched other forum threads like this, but nope of them helped me. My Application.mk looks like this:

```
    APP_PLATFORM := android-14
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a # build for the ARM version of MCPE
APP_CFLAGS := -O2 -std=gnu99 # optimization level 2, use C99 (for decleations in for loops, etc)

APP_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++11
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -std=c++11
APP_STL := stlport_static
```

Please help me!

Comment: Run ndk-build with V=1 and cut/paste the failing command line and error here.

Comment: Code would be good too.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322103/android-ndk-cant-find-stlport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class std::string has not been declared because it's not there. Unfortunately, there is no std::string in NDK. Some ports of std::string exist, I remember I found one or two, but finally I decided just not to use std::string. Why? Because we already have Java strings and C strings, Java strings come from JNI calls, C strings come from files, and if you introduce one more string type, it will be more conversion than usage.

EDIT: but read the comment below.

Comment: Huh? `std::string` can certainly be used in code built with the NDK - I've done so myself. Perhaps you're talking about the minimal system C++ runtime (`APP_STL := system`), but the OP is using `STLport`. Quoting from the NDK documentation regarding STLport: _"It will provide you with a complete set of C++ standard library
headers"_.

Comment: It doesn't help. I'm using the newest (r10) ndk.